# ToolTip stays open

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I need to show `ToolTip` on a certain control for a certain period of time, with this code I get the `ToolTip` to show, but it won't disappear:

```
Public Sub tooltipControl(ByVal kontrola As Object, ByVal opened As Boolean, ByVal Optional poruka As String = "", ByVal Optional boja As Object = Nothing)
    Dim ellipse1 As New Ellipse
    ellipse1.Height = 25
    ellipse1.Width = 50
    ellipse1.Fill = Brushes.Gray
    ellipse1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left


    Dim bubble As New ToolTip
    bubble.PlacementTarget = kontrola 
    bubble.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom
    ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(kontrola, 5000)
    Dim bdec As New BulletDecorator
    Dim littleEllipse As New Ellipse

    littleEllipse.Height = 20
    littleEllipse.Width = 20
    littleEllipse.Fill = boja
    bdec.Bullet = littleEllipse

    Dim tipText As New TextBlock
    tipText.Text = poruka
    bdec.Child = tipText
    bubble.Content = bdec

    bubble.IsOpen = True
    kontrola.ToolTip = bubble
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`, give your variable names actual meaning, not the same as the class. Fix those first... Also functions are for returning, you are not, make it a sub...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i have turned on Option Strict, changed the variable names and my function is now a Sub. Tooltip still shows up and stays there.

Comment: Please update your post with your changes... Also look into setting `TooltipService.ShowDuration` on the control.

Comment: Just for grins. comment out `bubble.IsOpen = True`.  I have been learning WPF and I don't see where I ever set this property in XAML or code.

Answer (score -1):

Set the duration on the elemtent the tooltip belongs to

```
ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(kontrola, 5000)
```

and add the tooltip before opening it

```
kontrola.ToolTip = bubble
bubble.IsOpen = True
```

Comment: I have tried that before, everything is the same, ToolTip opens but it stays opened until i close the form.